# Setup indexed search with news extension

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-11.x, tx-indexed-search

I use the "indexed_search", "crawler" and "news" extensions in TYPO3 11.5 and I want to search for news entries. There is an [example](https://docs.typo3.org/p/tomasnorre/crawler/main/en-us/Configuration/Examples/News/Index.html) in the crawler extension. I modified it to invoke the indexer for the crawled urls, as I found lots of other code fragments on the web that do it similarly:

```
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets {
   tx_news = &tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[news]=[_TABLE:tx_news_domain_model_news; _PID:57; _WHERE: hidden = 0]
   tx_news {
     pidsOnly = 58
     procInstrFilter = tx_indexedsearch_reindex
   }
}
```

The crawler log shows a log entry for each news entry. The URLs in the log entry are correct. Unfortunately the search only works for the last news entry. This isn't really surprising: I think that `tx_indexedsearch_reindex` will completely replace the index on each invokation. So I wonder how this is supposed to work.